# Passing values from one array to another in assembler

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I enter assembler function with two C char arrays like that:

```
EncryptAsm(arr1,arr2)
```

where both are of type `char*`, one containing text and the second one is full of '#' signs and it acts like two dimensional array, both are the same length.

I'm trying to pass some values from first array to second one in asm procedure:

```
mov ecx,row ;calculating index of arr2   index=[row*inputLength+column]
imul ecx,ebx
add ecx,column

mov eax,1 ;calculating index of arr1
imul eax,iterator

mov esi,arr1[eax]
mov edi,arr2[ecx]

movsb
```

When the indexes of both arrays equal 0 (`eax` and `ecx` are 0) everything is fine, but if it's bigger it doesn't work and throws an error (eg. `eax`==1).

In asm code, the arrays are of type:

```
arr1:ptr byte, arr2:ptr byte
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check the assembly guide of the movsb? If a normal Intel movsb,
it shall code like this:

```
CLD
MOV ECX ,100
LEA ESI,FIRST
LEA EDI,SECOND
REP MOVSB
```

And also, something needed to be checked:

1, the segment of SI/DI, if write access and segment length are right

2, interrupt protection during the REP MOVSB